# C言語で小数点第1位まで表記したい

Tags: c

それぞれの科目の点数を入力し、合計点、平均点を算出するコードなのですが、平均点を小数点第1位まで表記する方法がわかりません。どのようにすればよろしいですか。

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  double a, b, c, Sum, Ave;
  printf("Input your scores:\n");
  printf("Math: ");
  scanf("%lf", &a);
  printf("English: ");
  scanf("%lf", &b);
  printf("Science: ");
  scanf("%lf", &c);

  Sum = a + b + c;
  Ave = Sum / 3;
  if (Sum <= 179)
    printf("Your grade is F, Average is %.lf.\n", Ave);
  if (Sum >= 180 && Sum <= 209)
    printf("Your grade is C, Average is %.lf.\n", Ave);
  if (Sum >= 210 && Sum <= 239)
    printf("Your grade is B, Average is %.lf.\n", Ave);
  if (Sum >= 240 && Sum <= 269)
    printf("Your grade is A, Average is %.lf.\n", Ave);
  if (Sum >= 270)
    printf("Your grade is A++, Average is %.lf.\n", Ave);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 質問の本題と関係ありませんが、単独の if を列挙する代わりに else if を使えば `Sum >= 180` などの条件が不要になります。

Answer (score 1):

`%lf` の代わりに `%.1lf` と書けば小数点第1位までの表示に揃えられます。

```c
printf("Your grade is F, Average is %.1lf.\n", Ave);
```